# How to enable internet access from multiple computers simultaneously using Cisco Linksys WRT54GH?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, vpn

My desktop connects to the internet using a broadband connection modem. Between my desktop and ISP-provided modem I have connected a Cisco Linsys WRT54GH wireless router. My laptop can also connect to the internet using the wifi, set up using the router.

Now my problem is that desktop and laptop cannot connect to the internet at the same time using this modem-router setup. I have set "max number of users" option from router setup to 10 without any luck.

If one machine is connected, other one just keeps on saying "Connecting ..." without giving any error but no connection is established from the second machine.

Can someone tell me what can I try so that both machines can connect to the internet at the same time? Is it something to do with my ISP?

I am running Windows 7 on both machines.

Comment: Is the router running DHCP? If not, your ISP will likely only give one IP address at a time.

Comment: Are the IP addresses statically set on both the laptop and desktop to the same address?

Comment: I do not have static IPs on any of my machines. ISP hasn't given me any static IP address. So it's DHCP I would say. Please bear with me if I have misunderstood your questions. I am not into networking as such.